# Why are the print capabilities always empty?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I'm getting a print queue for various printers installed locally by doing:

```
var queueName = "Myprinterqueue";

using (var ps = new PrintServer())
using (var pq = ps.GetPrintQueue(queueName))
{
    pq.Refresh();
    var status = pq.QueueStatus;
    var jobs = pq.NumberOfJobs;
    var averagePagesPerMinute = pq.AveragePagesPerMinute;
}
```

`Status` and `NumberOfJobs` are retrieved correctly. But many other print capabilities, eg. `AveragePagesPerMinute`, are always empty or 0.

Why is this?

Comment: Have you tried to call [Refresh()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.refresh) before reading those properties?

Comment: @Jimi Yes. No change.

Comment: ...and are you sure that the Print Server / Printer driver provide this information? Call `[PrintQueue].GetPrintCapabilities()` to see what's available.

Comment: Why do I need a reference to `ReachFramework.dll` for me to use `GetPrintCapabilities`?

Comment: Well, [PrintCapabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printcapabilities) is part of the same namespace, but included in a different assembly: `ReachFramework.dll` instead of `System.Printing.dll`.

Comment: `AveragePagesPerMinute` is not included in the capabilities returned.